# PHP File....refresh page using submit button

Tags: onclick, form-submit, page-refresh

Hello Everyone,I Would like to refresh page after clicking on Submit button or i would like to refresh page after form submit.Please help me

thanks

Comment: hmm sounds as simple as `<button onclick="somejs">Hello</button>` the 'somejs' in the onclick event is something like window.location.reload()

Comment: if you want to refresh the page and not just head to the form page, use the header function: header('refresh:0;url=current url')